# Calculating $ \lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{\log\log x }{ \sqrt{\log x}}. $

Tags: calculus, limits

I didn’t do limits in quite a while so forgot how to evaluate everything but trivial ones. What I need help with is the following

$$ \lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{\log\log x }{ \sqrt{\log x}}. $$

I guess I just need to factor it but I don’t see how.

Comment: Substitution $t=\log x$, knowing that $t\to\infty$ when $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Replace $y =\log x$. Then it is equivalent to calculate the limit $$ \lim_{y \to\infty} \frac{\log y }{ \sqrt{y}}. $$ Does this help?

Comment: Hint. Find $\lim_{t \to\infty} \frac{\log(t) }{ \sqrt{t}}$

Comment: I think it does

Answer (score 3):

The limit is equivalent to

$$\lim_{y \to\infty} \frac{\log y }{ \sqrt{y}}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{z}{e^{z/2}}$$

which is now simple to evaluate.